# Nuxt: displaying an image from contents directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a use-case wherein the contents directory besides the markdown and yaml files I have images too. Reason being it is convenient to have a set of related files in a subdirectory. I am aware of displaying images using the `assets` and `static` directories.

The Content directory is as shown:

```
content
    - topics
        - topic-a
            content.yaml
            cover.png
        - topic-b
            content.yaml
            cover.png
```

Is there a way to access the png and display it? Thanks.

Comment: Display it from where? A page outside of `content` (e.g., `pages/index.vue`)?

Comment: (1) Within the blog page content for example. Also, (2) I would like to use a dynamic og:image URL  using the image stored in the page directory (assume each page has a directory). Thanks @tony19

Comment: This link: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/106 seems to have the answer. Let me check and confirm